# unable to post the data with bool value in asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-web-api

I am working on asp.net mvc webapi with EF code first with existing database. I have a class like,

```
public class User
{
public bool IsAgree{get; set;}
}
```

Iam using MySql database, my table looks like.

```
--------------
|ID  |IsAgree|
--------------
|int  |tinyint|
--------------
```

and i have a post action like

```
public HttpReponseMessage PostUser(HttpRequestMessage request,User user)
{
// some code to handle user data..
}
```

and from my view i am trying to post some data to the action like,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var sendata = {"IsAgree":true};
            $.ajax({
                url: '/api/account',
                type: 'POST',
                data: sendata,
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.status);
                },
                error: function (xhr) { alert(xhr.status); }
            });
        });
```

when i put breakpoint at action it shows user as `null` and i get alert message as `400` i.e. bad request. Is my json data was well for my model?  Please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to send the data in this way :

> data: JSON.stringify({ sendata })